# How scale up/out mechanism works in OpenStack and Cloudfoundry integration?

Tags: cloud, openstack, cloud-foundry

I just started investigating OpenStack & Cloudfoundry recently, and I just wonder how scale up/out mechanism works in OpenStack & Cloudfoundry integration.
As far as I understand, if we need to scale-up a web app, Cloudfoundry will try to create a new container to run new web app. If it reach to some limitation that it cannot allocate/create new container, would it try to use OpenStack to scale-up a new compute to service?
Thanks

Comment: OpenStack and CloudFoundry are not tightly coupled. Can you clarify if you are speaking about scaling an application deployed on OS and CF separately or whether you are wondering about deploying a Cloud Foundry instance on OpenStack?

Comment: Hi Jake. I wonder how scale out mechanism works in a cloud which deploys a CloudFoundry instance on OpenStack. Because as far as I understand OS provisions VM, CF provisions apps, how they works together in practical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Foundry is typically deployed on the infrastructure (OpenStack, vSphere, AWS) using [BOSH](https://bosh.io/). BOSH will create the VMs and install the packages necessary to run the CF platform. Increasing the VMs or compute services available to CF is done by BOSH, typically as a manual operation. There is no built-in mechanism for CF to request more compute capacity from the infrastructure via BOSH.

There have been some community efforts to add the ability to BOSH to auto-scale compute capacity on request from a package that has been installed by BOSH. See https://github.com/nttlabs/bosh-scaler as an example.